# Change in place" the selected value in ComboBox in c#

Tags: c#

I have a Combobox, I want to "Change in place" the selected value in comboBox in c#, and I get its data from the database.
When I select an item from combobox, I want to edit in place and change it, I do that by clicking Update Button to change it. But it doesn't work!

```
SpmoDataBase.Instance.PhoneType.PhoneType_Edit(cmbPhoneTypeEdit.Text);
```

the error is:

> NullReferenceException Class
>
> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Can you try to get selected value first then parse.